# Inequality regarding orbits of groups

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I've been working on a question for a few days now, and I'm stuck on proving a claim that I don't know if there's any reason for it to be true. I'll write it here in the greatest generality I can think of, in hopes that someone might know to tell me if they see any reason for this to be true or untrue:\

**Prove or Find a counterexample**:

Let $G$ be a (perhaps infinite) group, and let $H$ be an abelian group. Suppose that $G$ acts on $H$ in a way such that the $G$-orbits in $H$ are finite. Let $a,b\in H$ be arbitrary. Is it true that 
$$\left|G_{a+b}\right|\le\max\lbrace\left|G_a\right|,\left|G_b\right|\rbrace$$
(where $G_x$ denotes the orbit of an element $x\in H$)?

I will be very grateful to anyone who can shed some light on this claim, or maybe suggest extra condition underwhich this might hold.

Thank you.

Comment: The fact that $H$ is an abelian group is irrelevant to the question, so perhaps you are missing something out.

Comment: In the case I'm working on $G$ is a $p$-adic Lie group, and $H$ is the Pontryagin dual of the corresponding Lie-algebra. There are extra assumptions that can be put on the action, as well as on $a$ and $b$, but I was hoping maybe a more general solution can be found :P..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an easy counterexample, let $G=H=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $G$ act on $H$ by fixing the elements $1,2\in H$, and let $g\in G$ swap the other elements of $H$ in pairs $\{-3,-2\},\;\{-1,0\},\;\{3,4\},\ldots$ or fix them according to the parity of the element of $g$. Then
$$G_1=\{1\},\quad G_2=\{2\},\quad G_3=\{3,4\}.$$
Note that the group structure of $H$ was irrelevant. For all we cared, as long as $a+b$ was different than $a$ and $b$, we could make the action do whatever we wanted differently to them.

I suppose it's possible you could make the statement true if there's supposed to be some interaction between the operations of $G$ and $H$, though I can't think of anything specific that would work.